# reward points as percent from total in opencart 2.1

Tags: sql, opencart

I`m new in opencart system, but i allready have a trouble :) i have around 9 000 products in my store, and i want to make a loyal client program in which program every client will get 1 poitn for 10 (depends on the value, for example EURO). It will take a week or more to add the reward points to every single product data page, so im thinking about some kind of SQL query to data base, to add 10 percent to this column(column for the loyal clients reward points) from the column with the price of the product! I hope you understood me, thank you (sorry for my english!)

Regards! :)

Comment: Please add your data field;  a sample of what you have and another of what you want. BTW, Do you have tried to write a request ? what are your DB engine ? (mysql ?)

Comment: It can not be done with a simple query. You need to write a script to perform this task, we can do it for you for some appropriate cost. Contact us on https://www.knowband.com, if you are interested.